# How can I get the resolve conflicts window back in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just downloaded the latest WebStorm 2016.3.2 for Windows and I have a few merging conflicts. However when I try to go `Local changes -> Git -> resolve conflicts` nothing happens?

How can I get the resolve conflicts window back?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to open the Conflicts tool window in the latest version of Webstorm (2022.2).

1. Open the Commit tool window by clicking **Commit** from the side panel. Alternatively, you can open the commit window from the menu bar (at the top): **View** -> **Tool Windows** -> **Commit**.
2. In the Commit tool window, click **Resolve**.
   [image]
3. In the Conflicts popup that appears, click **Merge...**.

Hopefully the OP has fixed merged his or her merge conflicts by now. But as there still wasn't an answer to this question 6 years later, this should help anyone looking for this feature in the future.